# Still getting "Binary Not Found" error even after building (Eclipse OSX Mtn. Lion)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I recently installed Eclipse for C/C++ on my mac. Whether I'm compiling C or C++, I still get every time: `Binary Not Found` even after I've built with no errors. I have Xcode installed with the Command Line Tools and GCC and G++ work perfectly fine from the mac terminal. Compiling is fine, at least to my knowledge, in Eclipse but running it won't work. The executable that eclipse creates, however, under the Debug folder of my project, also runs fine. Here's what Eclipse puts in the console when building

`make all 
Building file: ../test1.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"test1.d" -MT"test1.d" -o "test1.o" "../test1.c"
Finished building: ../test1.c

Building target: test1
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
gcc  -o "test1"  ./test1.o
Finished building target: test1`

I have my artifact set to executable and have tried everything I can think of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've figured it out. The problem was I was using the CrossGCC compiler but if I switched it to the MACOSX compiler all runs smoothly with both C and C++.

Comment: how we change the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Preferences > c/c++ > new c/c++ project wizard 
click on Cross GCC or MacOSX GCC then click on make toolchain(s) preferred